# Getting White Label Error when I am using @Controller although project structure is proper

Tags: spring-boot

I have created project using start.spring.io but when I am using @Controller I am getting white label error and when I have changed this to @RestController I am not getting any error. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don’t have an appropriate content type so spring doesn’t recognize the request, in general a regular controller also should work depending on your annotations.

You haven’t posted the code of the controller itself so we can only speculate.

In a nutshell, if you want to serialize the response into HttpResponse you should do something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("students")
public class SampleStudentsController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Student getStudent(@PathVariable int id) {
        return .... 
    }
}
```

Also note, there is a `@ResponseBody` annotation which is “included” automatically in the more “specialized” version of controllers `@RestController` which is used to REST interaction

Also consider reading [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller) for more information